# Insert record in the table based on existing row in SQL

Tags: sql

Please find the below sample data. The first table contains 2 rows. I need to get the rows where  ever it is begging with emp as next row with ID and Name as first row and rest of the columns remains same. Need your help to achieve the same. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: " I need to get the rows where ever it is begging with emp as next row with ID and Name as first row".  I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards for this question

```
SELECT ID,Name,sal,date FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID LIKE 'emp%
```

'
[Read more about wildcards](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-wildcards.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
INSERT  INTO Table2
(
    [ID], 
    [Name],
    [sal],
    [date]
)
SELECT  T2.[ID],
        CAST(T2.[ID] AS VARCHAR(20)),
        T2.[sal],
        T2.[date]
FROM    Table2   AS T2
WHERE   T2.[Name] LIKE 'emp%'
```

Please let me know if it solves your issue, or if some adjustments are needed